# Representing edge absence in adjacency matrix of weighted graph

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to implement in C some graph algorithms, using an adjacency matrix as support data structure.
I need to implement a weighted graph, with weigths represented by a real number.

Given that 0 and negative numbers would be a correct weight for an edge, how can I represent the absence of an edge between two nodes?

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe C99's [`nan()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nan.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use instead of a number (`double`) a structure like this:

```
struct weight
{
   double weight;
   bool edge_exists;
};
```

and create an adjacency matrix of `weight`'s. So if `edge_exist`s is false there is no reason to check the `weight`, otherwise `weight` will be meaningful.

I would use the above if every(?) `double` could be a possible weight value.

Answer (score 0):

What about a nonsensical (I'm guessing you're making the assumption all weights should be positive) number, such as -1?

This would keep the code light (no need to add extra data structures), and it would be simple to remember.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that negative numbers are accepted as weights

Comment: Funky! Ok, equality's answer is looking pretty good right now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C99 or later you can use the `INFINITY` macro defined in `math.h` and assign all non existent edges a weight of `INFINITY`.

Look here for more details on using infinity in C: [How to use nan and inf in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923837/how-to-use-nan-and-inf-in-c)

(You could also technically use NaN, but it's not guaranteed to be defined and I think using infinity works nicer in a lot a algorithms anyways)