# What is the difference between IND and NAN numbers

Tags: c++, nan, infinity

A NAN value means Not A Number and IND value means Indeterminate number. But what is the difference between these two. How can we represent both in c++.

Comment: IND? Or INF?  INF is standard for 'infinity'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what is the difference between these two.

They are both the same thing. Some platforms choose to display a non-number as some variant of `NaN`, while others choose to display it as some variant of `IND`.

> How can we represent both in c++.

`std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` (or `float` or `long double`, if you prefer).

Comment: Apparently, they are not the same, per-se. On Microsoft platform, IND appears to be a special case for NaN. Specifically, for IND, the exponent is 0xFF, and the mantissa is 0x400000. Any other nonzero mantissa gives a NaN.

Answer (score 3):

If your operation would generate a larger positive number than could be stored in a double, the operation will return `1.#INF` on Windows or inf on Linux

Some operations don't make mathematical sense, such as taking the square root of a negative number.Both `sqrt(-1.0)` and `log(-1.0)` would return a NaN, the generic term for a "number" that is "not a number".

Windows displays a NaN as  `-1.#IND` ("IND" for "indeterminate") while Linux displays `nan`. Other operations that would return a `NaN` include 0/0, 0*∞, and ∞/∞.

[Refernce Link1](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html)

[Refernce Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923837/how-to-use-nan-and-inf-in-c)

Comment: It's not Windows vs Linux, it's the compiler's standard library that dictates how NaN should be shown.

Comment: "Some operations don't make mathematical sense"
The operations do make mathematical sense, but the results can't be stored in a floating point number, i.e. sqrt(-1.0) is i, an imaginary number that can't be stored in a float

Comment: FYI: Program produced by msvc for C displays NaN as `nan(ind)`.

Comment: Or `-nan(ind)`.