# how do i make printf use 'nan' on w32?

Tags: c, printf, nan

working on a cross-platform calculator application, i just noticed that on W32 NaN/Inf values are converted differently to strings than on OSX/linux.
namely.

linux/OSX uses `nan` rsp `inf`, whereas W32 uses something like `1.#INF` resp. `1.#QNAN`.

what's the canonical way to get an identical representation on all platforms?

i'd like to avoid manually checking values with `isnan()` and `isinf()` and hardcoding the `inf` resp `nan` string representations.

(i read some comment in [What is the difference between IND and NAN numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288406) that the actual "culprit" is the libc implementation, rather than the platform).

Comment: There just isn't one, no standard demands the *string* representation of the double value.  Not even normal double values, sometimes a period and sometimes a comma.  The MSVC representation is fairly wonky, you can make it a [lot more wonkier](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130228-01/?p=5103) :)  You'll have to make it consistent yourself.

Comment: What is tricker is that you likely also want the reverse too - changing text - and all its variants - into a NaN.

Answer (score 1):

In C11 (and maybe earlier), these representations *are* mandated by the spec, at least partially. From ISO/IEC 9899:2011, section **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**, paragraph 8:

> A **`double`** argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles **`[-]inf`** or **`[-]infinity`** — which style is implementation-defined. A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles **`[-]nan`** or **`[-]nan(`** *n-char-sequence* **`)`** — which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined. The **`F`** conversion specifier produces **`INF`**, **`INFINITY`**, or **`NAN`** instead of **`inf`**, **`infinity`**, or **`nan`**, respectively.

Anything more than that, you're going to be on your own for, I'm afraid.