# How to check if a float is infinity/zero/denormal?

Tags: c, floating-point

```
int is_infinity/is_zero/is_denormal(float f){
    //do something, return 0 or 1
}
```

This is what I did for checking if a `float` is negative.  I want to do something similar for the other functions, but I'm not sure how.

```
int is_negative(float val){
    union sp_object copy;
    copy.frep = val;
    if((copy.irep & 0x80000000) != 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::isinf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf) etc. Maybe [`std::fpclassify`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/FP_categories) if you're after all kinds of values.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Doesn't matter. `fpclassify` is part of the C standard library.

Comment: @StoryTeller `std::fpclassify` isn't though

Comment: Look at the functions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math).  Specifically in the section *Classification and comparison*

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Comments don't need to be nearly as pedantic, they aren't answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use nan and inf in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923837/how-to-use-nan-and-inf-in-c)

Comment: Can I do them with bit fields packing/unpacking? if yes.. how?

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't want to make a big deal out of this, it's just that OP edited the tags following another of my comments and I was notifying the other comment authors if they wanted to improve their comments. `std::numeric_limits` certain doesn't apply though.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/isnan.html C99?

Comment: @HOHO You really don't want to get into bit fields if you don't have to. There are easier methods provided for you by C99

Comment: Shouldn't `is_negative(float x)` be just `{ return x < 0.f; }`?

Comment: @unwind Consider the difference with `x= -0.0f` and then between `is_negative(x)` and `return x < 0.f;`

Comment: I just tried `double d = -0.0; printf("%f\n", d); if (d < 0.0) printf("less\n");` which outputs `-0.000000` but not result of comparison. Never mind `float`, it is in my "yesterday" bin.

Comment: @HOHO Depending on coding goals, your implementation of `int is_negative(float val)` is a problem with 1) unexpected FP formats relative to `copy.irep` and 2) when `val` is a Not-A-Number.  In the second case, some NANs do not clearly consider a NaN with its "sign" bit set to be a _negative_ number.

Comment: @WeatherVane `double d = -0.0; if (d < 0.0) printf("less\n");` _should_ print nothing as `d` is not less than 0.0.   -0.0 and +0.0 have the same _value_, yet different signs.

Comment: @chux my point was unwind's comment `return x < 0.f;` but `-0.0;` is negative.

Comment: @chux Yeah, I guess that's a point although I consider `-0` to make little sense as a negative number. :)

Comment: @chux my first comment was an unnecessary point - the same as yours by the time I posted it.

Comment: @unwind True.  OP's `is_negative()` is more like a sign bit test than the arithmetic idea of _is_negative_.  Latter has ambiguity of definition when `x== -0.0` or `x== -NAN`.

Answer (score 9):

> I want to do something similar for the other functions

Avoid bit fields, [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376382/how-to-check-if-a-float-is-infinity-zero-denormal?noredirect=1#comment75753947_44376382), as it depends  on implementation specifics.  `<math.h>` contains macros to classify a `float`.  These macros work for `double` and `long double` too.

```
#include <math.h>

// Adjust returns values as desired.
int is_infinity_is_zero_is_denormal(float f) {
  if (isinf(f)) return 'i';
  if (f == 0.0f) return 'z';
  if (isnan(f)) return 'n';
  if (isnormal(f)) return 0;  // neither zero, subnormal, infinite, nor NaN

  // All that is left is de-normal/sub-normal.
  return 'd';
}
```

Or maybe simply

```
bool is_infinity_is_zero_is_denormal(float f) {
  return !(isnormal(f) || isnan(f));
}
```

---

Also see `int fpclassify(real-floating x);` to classify the number in one step.

> classifies its argument value as NaN, infinite, normal, subnormal, zero, or into another implementation-defined category.  C11 §7.12.3.1 2
>
> The number classification macros `FP_INFINITE FP_NAN FP_NORMAL FP_SUBNORMAL FP_ZERO` represent the mutually exclusive kinds of floating-point values. They expand to integer constant expressions with distinct values. §7.12 6

```
bool is_infinity_is_zero_is_denormal(float f) {
  // return fpclassify(f) & (FP_INFINITE | FP_ZERO | FP_SUBNORMAL);  // not good
  switch (fpclassify(f)) {
    case FP_INFINITE:
    case FP_ZERO:
    case FP_SUBNORMAL:
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Let the compiler handle the optimization.

Comment: Your last example is totally wrong, because the `FP_*` macros are not required to be defined as powers of 2, and actually they are not, at least in GCC and MSVC. It could have tons of false positive or not work at all if any macro would be equal to zero (actually `FP_ZERO` is 0 in MSVC).

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani Agreed.  Post amended.

Answer (score -1):

ISO C99 provides an `INFINITY` and `NAN` macro that can be compared against. It is recommended to use the functions `isfinite()`, `isnormal()`, and `isnan()`. Note that as EOF points out, comparing against the `NAN` macro will not determine whether a value is actually `NAN`.

For C99:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Classes.html#Floating-Point-Classes

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

For earlier code you're out of luck:

http://c-faq.com/fp/nan.html

Comment: You cannot find out whether a floating-point number is `NAN` by comparing it to `NAN`, because `NAN` compares unequal to all floating-point numbers and `NAN`.