# Finding the second highest number

Tags: c

I want to find the second highest number from a sequence *without using an array*.

The instructions are the following.

> You are given a sequence of integers as input, terminated by a
>   -1. (That is, the input integers may be positive, negative or 0. A -1
>   in the input signals the end of the input.)
>
> -1 is not considered as part of the input.
>
> Find the second largest number in the input. You may not use arrays.

What I did is this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, a, temp, sec;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if (a == -1) ;
            break;

        temp = a;
        while (1) {
            scanf("%d", &a);
            if (a == -1) {
                break;
            }
            if (a > temp) 
                sec = temp;
            else 
                sec = a;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", sec);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample test cases will be like the following ones.

```
Sample Test Cases
Input   
Test Case 1 
-840 -288 -261 -337 -335 488 -1
Output
-261
Test Case 2 
-840 -335 -1
Output
-840
```

I don't know where to get started and where I am getting wrong.

Comment: your above code is not correct for given input.

Comment: this is not giving the right answer. please, can you correct it?

Comment: it is giving the correct answer, what do you think the correct answer is?

Comment: for the first test case, the actual output is showing this
32764

Comment: ah - we though you were showing your output.

Comment: how would you do this if you were asked to do it in a conversation. I will recite a sequence of numbers to you, you cannot write them all down. When I finish you must tell me the value of the second highest number. How would you do it. Note , you can write 2 numbers down.

Comment: Think of doing this with cards. Separate out the Hearts. Shuffle them. Draw two cards. Now find the two highest cards; the rules are you can only draw one card at a time, and every time you draw one you must discard one so you're left with two cards in your hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't solve your homework, but will offer some hints:

1. You should give your variables clear names that reflect their purpose. Names like `i`, `a`, `temp` and `sec` make the code unnecessarily hard to reason about.
2. You should initialize all variables. For example, the initialization of `sec` is a bit iffy.
3. You don't need two loops.
4. The following `if` is a no-op (which means that the `break` that follows is executed unconditionally):

   `if (a == -1) ;`

Finally, and most importantly, there are three cases you need to handle when iterating over the numbers:

1. The current number is larger than the largest number seen thus far.
2. The current number is not larger than the largest but is larger than the second-largest number seen thus far.
3. The current number is not larger than the second-largest number.

Hopefully, this'll give you enough direction to make more progress. If you get stuck, please post another question.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INT_MIN -999999;  //define minimum value

int main() {
  int input, firstMax = INT_MIN;
  int secMax = INT_MIN;
  do {
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if (input == -1)
    break;

    if(input > firstMax) {  //find new first max value
        secMax = firstMax;  //set previous max to second max
        firstMax = input;   //update first max to new value
    }
    else if(input > secMax) {
        secMax = input;     //new second max value is found. update it
    }
  } while(1); 

  printf("%d", secMax);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `input <= firstMax &&` is for safa gaurd. it woun't hurt. And I didn't use library to confure him. He seems novice.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

**EDIT:** works for me in GCC version 4.3.4 on SUSE Linux 11

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  int i, a, temp, sec, largest;
  sec = INT_MIN;
  largest = INT_MIN;
  while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == -1) {
        break;
    }
    if (a > largest) {
        sec = largest;
        largest = a;
    } else if (a > sec) {
        sec = a;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", sec);
  return 0;
}
```

I haven't corrected some bad code smells but I've just made a quick and dirty answer

Comment: please provide a comment so that I can improve my answer , don;t just downvote

Comment: NMDV, `int sec = -INFINITY;` is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: I don't understand what that means, I just compiled this and it works. INFINITY is defined in math.h which I have included. this answer also corroborates this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923837/how-to-use-nan-and-inf-in-c)

Comment: Unless you meant to say it is undefined because it is implementation dependent , the OP did not specify his platform , I've now edited my answer to specify mine

Comment: Which part do you not understand the meaning: NMDV, `INFINITY`, _undefined behavior_, or something else?

Comment: about INFINITY being undefined, could you please elaborate

Comment: `INFINITY` is defined in `<math.h>`, it is some large value well outside the `int` range.  Assigning a value outside the `int` range to an `int` is the problem.  It is either _undefined behavior_ or _implementation defined behavior_ - I'll need to check that.  Why not use `sec = INT_MIN;` - no issues with that?

Comment: `sec = -INFINITY;` --> "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>


int main() {
  int a, first = INT_MIN, sec = INT_MIN;
  while(1){
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == -1)
      break;

    if(a > first) {
        sec = first;
        first = a;
    }
    else if(a > sec) {
        sec = a;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", sec);
  return 0;
}
```